# How to check that pool 'reuses' Thread

Tags: java, multithreading, threadpool

To check the subject I have wrote the code:

```
public class ThreadPoolTest {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws InterruptedException {
        for (int i = 0; i < 100; i++) {
            if (test() != 5 * 100) {
                throw new RuntimeException("main");
            }
        }
        test();
    }

    private static long test() throws InterruptedException {
        ExecutorService executorService = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(100);
        CountDownLatch countDownLatch = new CountDownLatch(100 * 5);
        Set<Thread> threads = Collections.synchronizedSet(new HashSet<>());
        AtomicLong atomicLong = new AtomicLong();
        for (int i = 0; i < 5 * 100; i++) {
            executorService.submit(new Runnable() {
                @Override
                public void run() {
                    try {
                        threads.add(Thread.currentThread());
                        atomicLong.incrementAndGet();
                        countDownLatch.countDown();
                    } catch (Exception e) {
                        System.out.println(e);
                    }


                }
            });
        }
        executorService.shutdown();
        countDownLatch.await();
        if (threads.size() != 100) {
            throw new RuntimeException("test");
        }
        return atomicLong.get();
    }
}
```

As you can see I use `HashSet<Thread>`

Its usage will be correct only if Thread immutable. at least within test.

As I understand equals/hashCode is not overriden and thus inherit from Object.

Thus, please answer if my test incorrect and where is mistake.
If you know more clever way, please share this.

Comment: Can you explain further what problem you're encountering? Your code runs fine in my project.

Comment: @Henrik I am not sure that I undestand correct how thread poll 'reuses' threads

Comment: I would argue that your code actually manages to verify that `test()` creates 100 threads and executes 500 small tasks using them. Your `RunTimeException`s would be thrown if that was not the case. Are you looking for shorter ways to prove this?

Comment: @Henrik despitre that experiment a long, I am nit sure that this output guarantees

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As mentioned in my comment, I would argue that your code actually manages to verify that `test()` creates 100 threads and executes 500 small tasks using them. Your `RuntimeException` assertions would definitely fire if that was not the case.

Another approach to verifying this is to use a [`ThreadLocal`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/ThreadLocal.html) to count the actual number of threads running.

I've created the following unit test which uses a `ThreadLocal` to count the number of threads created by the `Executor`. Try studying its output to be convinced of the number of threads created.

```
@Test
public void threadCounter() throws Throwable {
    ThreadLocal<Integer> number = new ThreadLocal<Integer>() {
        private final AtomicInteger values = new AtomicInteger();

        @Override
        protected Integer initialValue() {
            return values.getAndIncrement();
        }
    };

    ExecutorService threadPool = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(100);

    for (int i = 0 ; i < 500 ; i++) {
        final int count = i;
        threadPool.submit(() -> System.out.printf("%-4s : %-20s - %s\n", count, Thread.currentThread().getName(), number.get()));
    }

    threadPool.shutdown();
    threadPool.awaitTermination(10, TimeUnit.SECONDS);

    Assert.assertEquals(100, number.get().intValue());

}
```

Comment: I don't have junit at hand. By reading I don't understand where do you incrent threadLocal after first time

Comment: Also I think name can be reused. If first thread died - second has use this name

Comment: Copy the code to a ´main` method for the same effect. `initialValue` of the `ThreadLocal` instance gets called whenever a new thread accesses `number` for the first time. This causes `number` to be incremented.

Comment: good idea, and second part of my question - check if my code thread-safe

Answer (score 1):

> I am not sure that I undestand correct how thread [pool] 'reuses' threads.

A pool thread (a.k.a., *worker thread*) has a `run()` method, just like any other thread, and that's where the "re-use" happens.  Basically, the worker thread's `run()` method picks *tasks* (i.e., the client-supplied `Runnable` objects) from a queue, and it runs them:

```
class ReallySimplePoolWorker {

    public ReallySimplePoolWorker(BlockingQueue<Runnable> workQueue) {
        this->workQueue = workQueue;
    }

    public void Run( ) {
        while (...not shutting down...) {
            Runnable task = workQueue.take();
            try {
                task.run();
            } catch (Exception ex) {
                ...notify the pool object of the exception...
            }
        }
    }

    private final BlockingQueue<Runnable> workQueue;
}
```